# Flask, assertion error

Tags: python, flask

I want to terminate z process when I enter www.xxx.xx/stopwork in browser.

I have tried:

```
@app.route('/dowork',methods=['POST'])

def dowork():
...............
      def workit():
        ...................

       z = Process(target=workit)


       z.start()

       @app.route('/stopwork', methods=['POST'])

       def stopwork():

       z.terminate()

       return redirect('/') 

return redirect('/')
```

It works as it should - process is stopped. When I want to call /dowork again from the browser however. dowork() starts again, but I have an error in the browser:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

And the error from the app:

'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: stopwork

Is there a way to set an endpoint as blank after z.terminate is executed? So there is no overwriting happening later on?

Comment: what is this `def(workit)`? and is it inside `def dowork()`?

Comment: I have edited. Now it should be clearer. Yes, it is inside dowork() . As you can see workit() becomes a process.

Comment: It's hard to follow your code since your indentation is wrong, but somewhere you have `@app.route('/stopwork', methods=['POST'])` inside a function call. The first time that line executes it registers the endpoint. The second time it executes it tries to register the endpoint again and fails. You should define `stopwork` at the same level as dowork` so that you only register the endpoint once.

Comment: If I apply your solution I will not be able to relate to process z and terminate it. So it does not solve my problem

Comment: Is there any way to unregister endpoint by the end of stopwork() before it returns redirect??

Comment: This doesn't really work/scale. If the app is served in more than one thread then you get into trouble, if more than one `Process` is started you get into trouble, a combination of both gets even more twisted. Don't create and delete routes dynamically. Add the process ID to the session data and retrieve it from there for killing the process in a ”static” _/stopwork_ route.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work as it should.  Not even once.  It may appear to work, but the web application is not guaranteed to be single threaded, not even a single process.  So the stop request may be handled by a different thread or even process than the start request was handled.

You can not expect any value from a request to be accessible in another request unless you explicitly persist it somehow.  In a cookie or a database.  A `Process` instance cannot be persisted that way because part of its value is an external operating system level process.  You could save its process ID and maybe its parent process ID to be sure to recognise this pair when the stop request is made.  Here an example of how to use a session cookie for this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

import psutil
from flask import Flask, redirect, session, url_for


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'f\xa9\x85\xf0\xe9\x982\xc4\xf8\xa0k\x91\xa7\xef\x12y'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return (
        '<form action="/work/start" method="POST">'
            '<input type="submit" value="Start">'
        '</form>'
        '<form action="/work/stop" method="POST">'
            '<input type="submit" value="Stop">'
        '</form>'
    )


def work_it():
    while True:
        print('working...')
        sleep(1)


@app.route('/work/start', methods=['POST'])
def start_work():
    if 'work_process' not in session:
        process = Process(target=work_it)
        process.start()
        pid = process.pid
        parent_pid = psutil.Process(process.pid).parent().pid
        session['work_process'] = (parent_pid, pid)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/work/stop', methods=['POST'])
def stop_work():
    if 'work_process' in session:
        parent_pid, pid = session['work_process']
        try:
            process = psutil.Process(pid)
            if process.parent().pid == parent_pid:
                process.terminate()
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
        session.pop('work_process')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

It uses [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) to get the parent processes' PID and to terminate the process.

This ”solution” has some shortcomings. You can start a process per browser or maybe even several from the same browser if the browser allows to separate the cookies from different tabs/windows.  Firefox is doing this with the private window feature.  And to stop a process the cookie is needed.  So if you block or erase cookies, it's not possible to stop the process anymore with the Stop button.  Again Firefox as an example: When you close a private window, its cookies are gone.

So for a better or even real solution you need to store the data to identify a started process on the server in some database.  As Flask is database agnostic I did not come up with an example as you may use a completely different database approach in your web application than I would have chosen for the example.

Comment: Excellent work, BlackJack, you opened my eyes on this issue. It would be very educative to see how would you apply a solution with MySQL database.